# Doesn't df.style.format() apply to Excel in version 2.1.4 of pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to apply number formatting. I know how to apply it through `df.style.map`. However, it is not possible to apply it to all rows using `df.style.format()`. I'd like to know if I'm doing something wrong.

Currently pandas is using version 2.1.4. I wrote code like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['John', 'Isak'],
    'Value': [100000, 3000000000]
})

dfstyle = df.style.format(thousands=',')

with pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    dfstyle.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
```

[image]

This is the result. I referred to [the relevant site](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/style.html#Formatting-Values) in the official document.

Comment: You are doing it right. However, this will work only on your dataframe and will not transfer to your Excel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df.style.format(thousands=',')` only applies to environments like Jupyter notebooks. It doesn't affect the format in a `*.xlsx` file.

You could use `workbook.add_format()` to modify the format in a `*.xlsx` file.

```
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['John', 'Isak'],
    'Value': [100000, 3000000000]
})

with pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
    
    workbook  = writer.book
    # specify the sheet you'd like to apply the format.
    worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
    
    num_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '#,##0'})
    
    # specify the column that you want to apply the format.
    worksheet.set_column('B:B', None, num_format)
```